# Wikipedia Queries + Grequests

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-requests, wikipedia, grequests

I'm trying to query ~50 Wikipedia pages. I've been using the requests package to make GET requests, but I've been working on implementing grequests as I hear it has much better performance.

The performance improvement is really quite minimal for me. Am I doing something wrong?

```
import requests
import grequests
from urllib.parse import quote
from time import time

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles={0}&prop=pageprops&ppprop=disambiguation&format=json'
titles = ['Harriet Tubman', 'Car', 'Underground Railroad', 'American Civil War', 'Kate Larson']
urls = [url.format(quote(title)) for title in titles]

def sync_test(urls):
    results = []
    s = time()
    for url in urls:
        results.append(requests.get(url))
    e = time()
    return e-s

def async_test(urls):
    s = time()
    results = grequests.map((grequests.get(url) for url in urls))
    e = time()
    return e-s

def iterate(urls, num):
    sync_time = 0
    async_time = 0
    for i in range(num):
        sync_time += sync_test(urls)
        async_time += async_test(urls)
    print("sync_time: {}\nasync_time: {}".format(sync_time, async_time))
```

output:
        sync_time: 8.945282936096191
        async_time: 7.97578239440918

Thanks!

Comment: I see no question here. Do you want us to do a general analysis of `grequests` vs `requests` performance? Make your program ?x times faster because you "heard" something? Speaking of which, 8s for 50 pages looks adequate performance to me unless you're planning to process tens of thousands.

Comment: There are also dedicated libraries to write Wikipedia bots, you may be better off not reinventing the wheel here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests
import grequests
from urllib.parse import quote
from time import time

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles={0}&prop=pageprops&ppprop=disambiguation&format=json'
titles = ['Harriet Tubman', 'Car', 'Underground Railroad', 'American Civil War', 'Kate Larson']
urls = [url.format(title) for title in titles]

def sync_test(urls):
    results = []
    s = time()
    for url in urls:
        results.append(requests.get(url))
    e = time()
    return e-s

def async_test(urls):
    s = time()
    results = grequests.map((grequests.get(url) for url in urls))
    e = time()
    return e-s

def iterate(urls, num):
    sync_time = 0
    async_time = 0
    for i in range(num):
        sync_time += sync_test(urls)
        async_time += async_test(urls)
    print("sync_time: {}\nasync_time: {}".format(sync_time, async_time))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    iterate(urls,10)
```

This yields me:

```
sync_time: 22.14458918571472
async_time: 4.846134662628174

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I don't see any problem here